# React dropdown not being populated with values from Supabase response

Tags: reactjs, httpresponse, semantic-ui, supabase

I am attempting to show a dropdown with a list of books in React using Semantic UI. The list of books is fetched from a Supabase table. The response seems to be coming through correctly however the values are not being rendered on the screen. The dropdown collapses when I click on it but the options are empty. What am I doing wrong?

This is my React component:

```
// imports

export const CaptureWord = () => {
    const [bookOptions, setBookOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getBooks();
    }, []);

    const getBooks = async () => {
        const supabase = createClient(process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL, process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY);
        let { data } = await supabase
            .from('books')
            .select('*');

        setBookOptions(convertAll(data));
    };

    const convertAll = (books) => {
        let result = [];

        for (let book in books) {
            let optionBook = {
                key: book.id,
                value: book.title,
                text: book.title
            };

            result.push(optionBook);
        }

        return result;
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <Header as="h1">Capture Word</Header>
            </Container>

            <Form>
                <Grid container textAlign="left">

                    // ... columns

                    <Grid.Column width="12">
                        <Form.Field>
                            <Dropdown
                                name="book-select"
                                placeholder="Click to select book ..."
                                options={bookOptions}
                                selection
                                className="book-select book-title"
                            />
                        </Form.Field>
                    </Grid.Column>

                    // ... more columns

                </Grid>
            </Form>
        </>
    );
};

export default CaptureWord;
```

This is the response I receive from Supabase (as inspected in my browser's Dev Tools):

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Die Poort","slug":"die-poort"}, 
 {"id":2,"title":"Die Ongelooflike Avonture van Hanna Hoekom","slug":"hanna-hoekom"}, 
 {"id":3,"title":"Die Vrou op die Skuit","slug":"die-vrou"}]
```

I am using React version `17.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using `for (let book of books)`?

```
for (let book of books) {
    let optionBook = {
        key: book.id,
        value: book.title,
        text: book.title
    };

    result.push(optionBook);
}
```